# Tasks distribution is unbalanced against workers

Tags: apache-storm

Storm UI suggests that one of my bolt is a bottleneck. It is red when you visualize the topology and its capacity is over than 1 sometime it reaches 10. If I tried to investigate how the tasks were splitted against the workers. One worker is clearly idle. Althought It is used (not idle) for other bolts?

[image: The snapshot from storm ui]

Comment: Maybe your grouping is sending too much work to one bolt instance? Could you post your topology setup code (the part where you "setBolt" your bolt)? It's also possible that the worker that appears idle is restarting for some reason. Check the worker log for that worker to verify that it's not restarting.

Comment: I'm using shuffleGrouping().    
builder.setBolt("BOLT_NAME", new Bolt(),
                (getAnInt("PARALLEL")))
                .shuffleGrouping("PREVIOUS_BOLT","Stream");
The worker is not restarting. However, maybe it worth mentioning that this machine hosts both nimbus and supervisor !

Comment: It's fine to run Nimbus and a supervisor on the same machine. I'd look at what your bolt is actually doing, and whether it's managing to process and ack the input tuples in all code paths. The execute latencies you posted are extremely high, and if you look at the executed counts, it looks like you're only managing to get a few tuples through each bolt. Note that I believe when it says "20 tuples" processed, it's really saying "1-20 tuples" (has to do with the sampling rate for the processed tuple metric, it counts 5% of tuples by default if I recall)